# The area between $f(x)=x^2 - 1$ and $g(x)=sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x))$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$

Tags: calculus, integration

I Know that $g(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$.
I also know that they cut each other at $x=1, -1$.
Is it correct If I calculate the integral of $g(x)-f(x)$ only?
It seems that I need to divide the calculation somehow, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are right:

[image]

It suffices to calculate the integral of $g(x) - f(x)$ because, in fact, the red area is
$$
\color{red}{\int_{-1}^1g(x)dx}
$$
and the green one is
$$
\color{green}{\int_{-1}^1(-f(x))dx = -\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx}.
$$
[image]

The "green" integral can be seen as the area between the function $-f(x)$ and the $x$-axis, which is the same that you want to find.

In general, to find the area between two functions $f,g$ in a certain interval $I=(a,b)$, you must just calculate the integral of $|f(x)-g(x)|$, that is $g(x)-f(x)$ in your case because, as you said, $g(x)>f(x)\;\; \forall x\in(-1,1)$.